# 'twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to play with  [Twitter Bootstrap Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics) using Rails 4.0.0.rc1 and ruby 1.9.3p392.

Then I try to access 
`http://localhost:3000/products`

I'm having error:

> 'twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found.

Please see attached screenshot.

Code available at https://github.com/tenzan/twitter-bootstrap.git

[image]

Comment: try to remove  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc1' from Gemfile and bundle

Comment: I've commented out 'sass-rails' and run "bundle update" and restarted server - nothing changed

Comment: https://github.com/tenzan/twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/Gemfile

Comment: Rails 4 removed the need for an `:assets` group in the Gemfile. Do you have a specific reason for leaving that in?

Comment: No any specific reason to have :asset. It didn't work the other way so I just tried this way. I'm new to RoR. Now I've removed :assets following your advice and added *= require bootstrap_and_overrides to the application.css @shrikant1712 advised below and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to require Bootstrap LESS (bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less) in your application.css

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 */
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer is not actually correct. By default Rails adds `require_tree .` in your application.css which loads everything including bootstrap_and_overrides. The problem was that you had nested all the Bootstrap gems in an :assets group in your Gemfile. Once I removed that, it worked. The right answer is actually from @depa. :)

Comment: thanks for your kind information.actually I am not worked with Rails 4.0.0.rc1 that much

Answer (score 32):

I'm going to answer this noting that I am working on ruby 2 / rails 4 application (NOT rails 3)

Requiring Bootstrap LESS (bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less) in your application.css is meaningless here, because the pipeline comes already with "require_tree ." which automatically includes everything inside the folders of the asset pipeline.

After pulling my hair for several hours, I found that removing the 3 required gems from the group :asset in the Gemfile is the only way to fix it

So, Do Not do this in you Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails"
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
end
```

And instead DO this:

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

Comment: I did it, occured another error instead, that said `The less-rails plugin requires the asset pipeline to be enabled.`.

Comment: This answer worked for me , I was on bootsrap3, rails4 and ruby2

Answer (score 13):

The Bootstrap gem comes with it's own bundled version of Bootstrap which it will take responsibility for importing. Don't import the Bootstrap gem in the :assets group, or the gem assets won't be found.

Note that the assets group has been removed in Rails 4.

Comment: In fact Rails 4 has removed the assets group.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Bootstrap 2 and less on Rails 4.0.1.  I decided to upgrade to Bootstrap 3 but "twitter-bootstrap-rails" is still on Bootstrap 2.  There are a few gems available but I found the simplest approach was to add the css, js and fonts manually (followed these instructions [Using bootstrap 3 with rails 4](http://rvg.me/using-bootstrap-3-with-rails-4/)).

Follow these instructions, ensure "therubyracer" and "less-rails" gems are installed and then a few more steps are required to get less working with bootstrap 3 and rails 4:

- Download Bootstrap 3 source ([Bootstrap source](http://getbootstrap.com))
- Create directory "/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"
- Copy contents of bootstrap source "less" directory (lots of less files)
  to "/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"
- Create "bootstrap_and_override.css.less" in "app/assets/stylesheets".  Import "bootstrap.less" into "bootstrap_and_override.css.less", example of mine including a couple of test customisations:

  ```
  @import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
  @navbar-height: 120px;
  @body-bg: #F7911B;
  ```

Hope this is useful to anyone wanting to try Bootstrap 3 with less.

Answer (score 0):

for me, `less-rails` gem was missing from Gemfile and adding it and running `bundle` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to run

  `rails g bootstrap:install less`  
It worked like a charm