# Unable to load twitter-bootstrap-rails from a rails mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have converted am existing rails 3.2 application to a mountable engine, but the asset pipeline is  broken with the following error:

> 'twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found
>
> (in /Users/developer/Projects/messaging_app/app/assets/stylesheets/messaging_phase1/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)

And it fails while executing the following line in bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less

> @import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

I have verified that the twitter-bootstrap gem is installed and is loaded.

It seems that the bootstrap.less file from the gem is not loaded by the application after the application is converted to an engine.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the following lines to engine.rb, it worked.

```
require 'less-rails'
require 'less/rails/bootstrap'
```

myengine.gemspec has the following lines:

```
s.add_dependency 'less-rails-bootstrap'
s.add_development_dependency "therubyracer"
```

My app & engine specs:

- Rails 4.2,
- Ruby 2
- less & less-rails 2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You need this in `application.css` (see [here](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less)):

```
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
```

but you may also try, if it is enough to just use:

```
*= require_tree .
```

And if you are using Rails 4 (which apparently you do not) you should not include the bootstrap gems in an :assets group in your gemfile (see [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)). This was answered here [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665642/twitter-bootstrap-bootstrap-less-wasnt-found).

Comment: Hi AWM, I already had the require statements you have mentioned. The error: 'twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found, happens when rails loads bootstrap_and_overrides into application.css and it fails to find 'twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' from the gem.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to post your gemfile. Do you have the lines `gem 'therubyracer'` and `gem 'less-rails'` included in you gemfile? If not, you should. You should also remove any conflicting gems like `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`.

Comment: If this does not work, please post the `=require`- and `@import`-lines of your `application.css` and the `@import`-lines of your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`.

Comment: Any feedback on my suggestions?

Comment: We had a particular scenario in which a rails application was mounted as an engine into another. Twitter bootstrap was used by this engine. This scenario occurred because the engine was not loading twitter bootstrap. We fixed this by manually changing loadpath of the gem. Many thanks for your suggestions. :)